# Does Cygwin overwrite the windows command line?

Tags: bash, command-line, cygwin

I am a Mac user at home, but am forced to use a windows machine at work. I want to install Cygwin on my work machine to leverage the power of the bash prompt but I need to make sure that it doesn't replace the windows command line. I searched around on the internet and was unable to answer my question.

So, does anyone know... If I install Cygwin will the IT guy at my work still be able to use the Windows Command Prompt or will Cygwin replace it?

Answer (score 3):

It will not replace cmd. It is independent software.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, do it. Cygwin installs a bunch of programs that run under Windows. It does not remove or replace cmd.

Answer (score 1):

I use both CMD and Cygwin (via mintty) at work depending upon the situation. The IT guys use whatever they need to work on the system. Cygwin is installed into a separate directory and launches its own environment and doesn't remove anything that exists on your system.